# Mechanize and SSLError in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssl, mechanize

Using Mechanize with my ruby script, I can't get around the the well known SSLError.
I'm running on rails with Windows 7 and RailsInstaller.

I want to generate adcrun.ch links with my ruby script.
Therefore I have to login into my adcrun.ch account:

```
require 'mechanize'
a = Mechanize.new
page  = a.get( "http://adcrun.ch" )
login_form  = page.form_with( :action => "http://adcrun.ch/" )

login_form.usr_email = "myem@il.com"
login_form.usr_pass  = "mypassword"

page = a.submit( login_form, login_form.button_with( :value => "Login" )
```

Now when I run this code it shows me that SSLError state

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed

I have also included the newest ca file from http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
like this

```
a.ca_file "/RailsInstaller/cacert.pm"
```

or that

```
a.agent.http.ca_file "/RailsInstaller/cacert.pm"
```

but neither of the solutions worked.

Can someone give me hints?

Comment: Using your code, exactly as it is, works for me.  The only difference is I am on Linux. Works on both 1.8.7 and 1.9.3.  Could be the URL being http instead of https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you should be using `"https://adcrun.ch"` instead of `"http://adcrun.ch"`.  Currently, you are trying to make a secure connection on a non-secure port, therefore, you are getting an "invalid cert" returned and OpenSSL can't verify it.